# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestProtos/AuthMethodResponseProto

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, build

I was trying to build Hadoop commons project(truk) from github using maven.
But the build failed throwing the following error,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project hadoop-common: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestProtos/AuthMethodResponseProto: TestProtos.AuthMethodResponseProto -> [Help 1]
```

I didn't find any dependencies for the mentioned class. Is it related to my development environment.? or Did I missed something.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try doing `maven clean install` on the project folder **or** Right Click on project -> "Run as Maven Test". This will automatically download the missing plugin. And after that, Right Click on project ->"Update Maven project" it removes the error **or add**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.17</version>
</plugin>
```

to your depedencies.